# Teradata Sub Grouping

Tags: sql, function, subquery, teradata

I have the following Data in my table

```
Key  |Eff_DT  | End_Dt  | Ind
1    |Jan     | Mar     | Y
1    |Feb     | May     | Y
1    |Mar     | Jul     | Y
1    |Jun     | Aug     | N
1    |Sep     | Oct     | Y
1    |Nov     | Dec     | N
```

Expected result is

```
Key  |Eff_DT  | End_Dt  | Ind
1    |Jan     | Jul     | Y
1    |Sep     | Oct     | Y
```

**Explanation:**

I need to consider all the records between two rows which has Ind as 'N' and find Min of Eff_dt and Max of End_dt.

Which function should I use to achieve this ?

Comment: I guess those date field include Year too?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Eff_DT` and `End_Dt` are actually `DATE` columns:

```
select key, Ind, min(Eff_DT), max(End_Dt)
from
 (
   select key, Ind, Eff_DT, End_Dt,
      -- start a new group whenever "Ind" is not 'Y' using a cumulative sum of 0's and 1's
      sum(case when Ind ='Y' then 0 else 1 end) 
      over (partition by key
            order by Eff_DT 
            rows unbounded preceding)  as grp
   from tab
   qualify Ind = 'Y' -- only return the 'Y'  rows
 ) as dt
group by key, Ind, grp
```